# If language $P$ is not regular, is $\{ w \in \Sigma ^* : |w| \geq 1000 \}\cup P$ regular necessarily?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Prove or refute.

> Let $ L = \{ w \in \Sigma ^* :\ |w| \geq 1000 \} $. Let $ P $ be a non-regular language. Then $ L \cup P $ is regular necessarily.

I think it is true, but I don't have any idea about how to prove is formally. It is just that when the word becomes greater than 1000 it will be inside the language. Can you help me say it more formally please?

Comment: How many words shorter than 1000 do belong to the language?

Comment: A finit number , but how do i write it formally ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $P \cap L^c$. Such a set is necessarily finite (why?). Can you use closure properties of regular languages to finish the rest?

Comment: thanks for the hint! i need to think about it a little bit , I am not so good at automata ... why does such a set is necessarily finit ? and how can I use the closure properties to finish the rest ?

Comment: Because $|P \cap L^c| \le |L^c|$ and $L^c$ is finite. In particular $|L^c| = \sum_{i=0}^{999} |\Sigma|^i < |\Sigma|^{1000}$ if $|\Sigma| > 1$ and $|L^c| = 1000$ if $|\Sigma|=1$.

Comment: hey, steven! thank you so much for the help! , now I can understand better what is the complement of L, can you help me figure out what Papuseme meant when he said to use closure properties of regular languages to finish the rest? I really don't know what to do now, please